# Combining PowerShell Prompt functions (e.g. ConsoleZ with posh-git)

Tags: git, powershell, posh-git

This is my ConsoleZ powershell that I wanted to have a posh-git environment also, but doesn't work.

[image: ConsoleZ power-shell]

This line of code is inside the Microsoft PowerShell profile

```
Write-Host "Setting up GitHub Environment"
. (Resolve-Path "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\GitHub\shell.ps1")

Write-Host "Setting up Posh-Git"
. (Resolve-Path "$env:github_posh_git\profile.example.ps1")



function prompt {
  $p = Split-Path -leaf -path (Get-Location)
  "$p> "
}
```

I have been trying a couple of time now, posh-git won't integrate on to my consoleZ.

The problem is it won't run posh-git after putting all the scripts needed in the $profile.

I can't get it to be like this.

[image: Example consoleZ with posh-git running]

**UPDATE**

Burt_Harris comment was right, it was because of the prompt function that was messing with posh_git, now my problem is how to get the 2 functions working?

**UPDATE 2**

My script to combine the two prompt functions. just give me PS> instead of folder directory>

```
# Prompt for shortened link on command line
function myPrompt {
    $p = Split-Path -leaf -path (Get-Location)
    "$p> "
}

$myPrompt = $function:myPrompt

# Set up a simple prompt, adding the git prompt parts inside git repos
function posh_gitPrompt {
    $realLASTEXITCODE = $LASTEXITCODE
    Write-Host($pwd.ProviderPath) -nonewline
    Write-VcsStatus
    $global:LASTEXITCODE = $realLASTEXITCODE
    return "> " 
}

# Combine myPrompt & posh_gitPrompt
function global:prompt {
    "myPrompt`n$(&$posh_gitPrompt)"
}
```

**SOLUTION**

Instead of using this

```
Write-Host($pwd.ProviderPath) -nonewline
```

on the posh_git example profile, I modified it to

```
Write-Host(Split-Path -leaf $pwd.ProviderPath) -nonewline
```

that did the trick, didn't need to make another function.

Comment: My question is what is wrong with the script i have for my $profile. I can't seem to get posh-git running with consoleZ. The git environment works with consoleZ but posh-git doesn't display on consoleZ.

Comment: Perhaps posh-git (which I've never used) operates by replacing the prompt function, and your script replaces it's prompt function with it's own.   Try putting `function prompt` at the beginning of your script.

Comment: @Burt_Harris completely right, do you know how to make the two prompt function work at the same time? any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using this

```
Write-Host($pwd.ProviderPath) -nonewline
```

on the posh_git example profile, I modified it to

```
Write-Host(Split-Path -leaf $pwd.ProviderPath) -nonewline
```

that did the trick, didn't need to make another function.

Answer (score 0):

Save away the old prompt function and call it in your overridden version, concatenating the different information together.   For example:

```
$previousPrompt = $function:prompt

function prompt() { 
    "MyPrompt`n$(&$previousPrompt)"
    }
```

Comment: function global:prompt {
    "myPrompt`n$(&$posh_gitPrompt)"
}